# Hosting workshops with all participants sharing screens

Tags: video-conferencing, screen-sharing

I'm looking for a conference software to host in-company remote coding workshops.

The perfect solution would allow the host to see all the participants screens - as s gallery view with the possibility to zoom to single participant's screen. Preferably with the participant seeing host's pointer. The participants would only see one of the host's (dual) screens or a single window. The host does not need to take over participant's machine.

The only thing I found so far is [Zoom](https://zoom.us), but I think with multiple screen sharing, everybody sees everybody's screen. As far as I've checked Skype, WebEx and Hangouts lack simultaneous screen sharing.

Primary OS is Windows 10. Lack of support for other OSes (Linux, Mac) is not a deal breaker.
Price is not an issue. Any sensible subscription will do.